# Query posts from category A, and from either category B or C

Tags: wp-query, categories

I need to get posts belongs to few categories, but it should match following rule.

let say I have category ids 100,105 & 106.

then I need `100 && ( 105 || 106 )` this rule.

I know following rules for separate `OR` & `AND`,

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '100,105,106' ) );  // 100 || 105 || 106
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__and' => array( 100,105,106 ) ) ); // 100 && 105 && 106
```

But I need something like `100 && ( 105 || 106 )`. How can I do that with `WP_Query` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best way, but I have managed to get the desired result set with following `$args` parameters.

```
$args['tax_query'] =    array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => array(100),
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => array(105,106),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Set up your terms in php beforehand and then pass them to wp_query as a variable.

```
$mycats = array( ...
   some logic
);
```

and then

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $mycats ) );
```

Comment: ...perhaps you'd like to explain the down votes?